# RSelenium: clicking a link within another link

Tags: r, selenium, web-scraping, dplyr, rselenium

I have this `RSelenium` script:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(RSelenium) # running through docker
library(rvest)
library(httr)

remDr <- remoteDriver(port = 4445L, browserName = "chrome")
remDr$open()


remDr$navigate("https://books.google.com/")
books <- remDr$findElement(using = "css", "[name = 'q']")

books$sendKeysToElement(list("NHL teams", key = "enter"))

bookElem <- remDr$findElements(using = "xpath",
                               "//h3[@class = 'LC20lb']//parent::a")

links <- sapply(bookElem, function(bookElem){
  bookElem$getElementAttribute("href")
})
```

The above clicks every link on the Google search return (there are 10 per page). The books that I search mostly have a preview once you click into it. If there's a preview, there's a small `About this book` link to click on that brings you to the publishing info.

I want to click on the first links, and then if there's a preview, click on "About this book." I have the below, but I just get `Error: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable` errors:

```
for(link in links) {

  # Navigate to each link
  remDr$navigate(link)

  # If statement to get past book previews
  if (str_detect(link, "frontcover")) {

   link2 <- remDr$findElement(using = 'xpath', 
                               '//*[@id="sidebar-atblink"]//parent::a')
   link2 <- as.list(link2)
   print(class(link2))
   link2_about <- sapply(link2, function(ugh){
      ugh$getElementAttribute('href')
    })

  } else {
    print("nice going, dumbass")
  }
}
```

Or I try a `for` loop instead of a the `sapply`, I get `Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors`:

```
for(link in links) {

  # Navigate to each link
  remDr$navigate(link)

  # If statement to get past book previews
  if (str_detect(link, "frontcover")) {

    link2 <- remDr$findElement(using = 'xpath',
       '//a[@id="sidebar-atb-link" and span[.="About this book"]]')

     for(i in length(link2)){
      i$getElementAttribute('href')
     }

    } else {
     print("dumbass")
   }
}
```

How can I successfully click into that second link, depending on if the preview is there? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just update the below line.

```
aboutLinks <- remDr$findElements(using = 'xpath', 
                           '//a[@id="sidebar-atb-link" and span[.="About this book"]]')
links2 <- sapply(aboutLinks, function(about_link){
  about_link$getElementAttribute('href')
})
```

Comment: Still get that confusing `Error: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable` error, unfortunately. Must be something to do with the following `sapply` function? As in, your elements are definitely correct, but something after that isn't working

Comment: `link2 <- as.list(link2)` why you are doing this?

Comment: I read somewhere that that could have been giving me that error.. but who knows. Same error either way

Comment: Done - same error. Might be my machine? Though, if I comment out the `sapply` part, and `print(link2)`, it does print out the correct number of links. Just the `sapply` throws that subsettable error

Comment: Ok, figured out the issue. We missed `s' while getting the `About this book` links. we should pass elements to `sapply`, not an element.